# How do I build a Nodejs App and deploy on a local LAN network with out Nodemon

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In a react App I can build it using a

```
//package.json 

 "build": "react-scripts build",
```

and serve it on my local LAN using

```
serve -s build
```

My question is how do I build a Nodejs App and serve it on my Local LAN.
I know that I can run it on my localhost:port using nodemon and access the App on my local network.
but I am trying to find how to create a build of the APP and serve it on my Local LAN.

Comment: `nodemon` just restarts an application when it exists, it has nothing to do with listening for network requests on a LAN. That is done by the application itself, and you've told us nothing about it (not even what type of requests it is listening for).

Comment: You use `node` ... to run it as a windows service look at various packages that would help you do that.

Answer (score 1):

If your 'webserver' is Windows, look at [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode). It integrates with IIS, which would allow users on your LAN to visit the app page using the server's FQDN.
If you're serving the app from a Linux machine, look at [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/). Hope this helps :)